# DMARC report: systematic SPF failure for a domain

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I get DMARC reports sent from various different sources.
All of the reports generally have `<result>pass</result>` for all of the sections.

However, the reports from Google always have SPF fails:

```
<row>
    <source_ip>185.116.215.174</source_ip>
    <count>1</count>
    <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
    </policy_evaluated>
</row>
.
.
.
<auth_results> 
    <dkim>
        <domain>domain.co.uk</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>dkim</selector>
    </dkim>
    <dkim>
        <domain>email-od.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>dkim</selector>
    </dkim>
    <spf>
        <domain>bounce.domain.co.uk</domain>
        <result>fail</result>
    </spf>
</auth_results>
```

My SPF record looks like:

`"v=spf1 +a +mx +a:server.domain.co.uk include:email-od.com ~all"`

I am unsure why my bounce domain is failing SPF checks, but it only seems to be on Google DMARC reports.

To be honest, I am unsure what the bounce domain `bounce.domain.co.uk` does, should I set up an email address `bounce@bounce.domain.co.uk`?

Any help sorting my SPF and advice regarding `bounce.domain.co.uk` would be great.

Answer (score 1):

bounce.domain.co.uk should have an SPF record in order to pass authentication check
and header from domain should be equal or aligned with bounce.domain.co.uk in order to pass DMARC check

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should bounce.domain.co.uk not be covered in the SPF that i have, in particular this section `"v=spf1 +a +mx +a:server.domain.co.uk`

Comment: The IP address, from which bounce.domain.co.uk sends, need to covered by that spf record. You can use any spf lookup tool, e.g. easydmarc.com/tools to check of sending IP is there